# Classes of outer totalistic cellular automata

Tags: cellular-automata, data-sets

I'm wondering if anyone knows of any place where the Wolfram classifications of many outer totalistic cellular automata have been catalogued. The classes of a few examples are given in *A New Kind of Science*, famously that of Rule 224 (Life) or more simply ones like Rule 0 which kills all of the cells. I'm wondering if there's any place where these classes have been collected, for a research project. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [fairly old link](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/ca/wolfram.html), which only lists a few classes specifically, but it might be a place to start.

I'd agree with David Eppstein that a longer list might not be all that useful.  There's no quick way to tell for sure whether a given CA rule is Class 4, except in the really simple cases.  In many cases, with enough work you may be able to design persistent structures that could support universal computation.